# How do I limit outgoing mail in IIS

Tags: windows, email

I am going to use C# to write e-mails into the Pickup directory.  Each e-mail will have a 3-5mb pdf attachment.  There will be about 500-700 e-mails dropped into the pickup directory at one time. I setup a domain in IIS for my hostgator e-mail account which I would like to use to send out these e-mails.

Hostgator limits to 500 emails per hour.  My internet connection speed is 3mb down and 768kb up.

How or where can I limit how many e-mails are sent out at a time in IIS?  And what should the settings be?

Thanks,

Jake

Comment: What's wrong with letting hostgator limit the e-mails to 500/h?

Comment: Well, as it is... won't IIS try to send out all of the e-mails one after another?  What if it sends out 700 within an hour?  Is there not a way to limit how many e-mails per x minutes/hours etc. in IIS so that I can stay within hostgators limits?\

Comment: Yes, IIS would dump all of the outgoing e-mail on the SMTP MTA. I'm asking, why not simply allow hostgator to limit your outgoing e-mail? There is no easy way to implement this in the MTA or IIS. The application would have to be written in such a way as to limit output frequency.

Comment: If you send over 500/hr the e-mails will fail and may bounce back with an undeliverable error.  I guess I could put a timer on it in C#.  If the retrieved rows is >= 475, process 475 then wait an hour before processing the rest.  Or write 5 e-mails to the pickup folder ever 36 seconds.  When I say processing I mean writing the e-mail to the pickup folder.

Comment: Maybe not applicable to your situation, but if you can get IIS to relay through an Exchange 2010 server, [this question/answer](http://serverfault.com/questions/322692/preventing-email-blasts-with-exchange-2010-ip-throttling-or-any-other-technolog) talks about throttling messages.

Comment: If the bounce message is an error code is in the 400 range then the MTA should wait and retry the e-mail. If the error code is in the 500 range then hostgator is violating RFC.